# 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dll, unity-container, asp.net-web-api

I'm adding WebApi to an existing MVC3 app, and after adding the NuGet Web Api package and getting new Unity.dll, I'm having the following problem:

Apparently another assembly is referencing the Unity.dll (I believe it's EnterpriseLibrary.Common, not 100% sure - I did update to the latest EntLib and I'm still getting the error).

I've added the below assemblyBinding to the web.config. But the assembly binding is NOT working and it's still looking for the old Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll.

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.Unity" PublicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" Culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.414.0" newVersion="2.1.505.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration" PublicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" Culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.414.0" newVersion="2.1.505.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
```

Here is the stacktrace from the error I'm seeing:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)</Message><StackTrace>
Server stack trace: 
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, ObjectHandleOnStack retTypes)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerTypeResolver.GetControllerTypes(IAssembliesResolver assembliesResolver)
   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.WebHostHttpControllerTypeResolver.GetControllerTypes(IAssembliesResolver assembliesResolver)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerTypeCache.InitializeCache()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, ObjectHandleOnStack retTypes)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerTypeResolver.GetControllerTypes(IAssembliesResolver assembliesResolver)
   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.WebHostHttpControllerTypeResolver.GetControllerTypes(IAssembliesResolver assembliesResolver)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerTypeCache.InitializeCache()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.InitializeControllerInfoCache()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()

Exception rethrown at [1]: 
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, ObjectHandleOnStack retTypes)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerTypeResolver.GetControllerTypes(IAssembliesResolver assembliesResolver)
   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.WebHostHttpControllerTypeResolver.GetControllerTypes(IAssembliesResolver assembliesResolver)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerTypeCache.InitializeCache()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.InitializeControllerInfoCache()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsyncInternal(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)</StackTrace></Exception>
```

Comment: I just copied the old version of the .dll over to solve this problem temporarily... fortunately I didn't need the new one for anything.